# spark & java COMPILATION ERROR

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

When I used maven to compile spark java program, I got an compilation error like this

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/spark/java/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[9,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable read
  location: variable spark of type org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

here is my JAVA pragram

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;


public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "/home/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<String> logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache();
//    Dataset<String> logData = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate().read.textFile(logFile).cache();
    long numAs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("a")).count();
    long numBs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("b")).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);

    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

I write the program follow the  official website :
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html
how this error comes..??

here is my pom.xml

```
<project>
  <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you add the right dependency?

Comment: Can you also include `pom.xml` file in the question?

Comment: here is my pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok...    I found the result..
the example in offical website is wrong ..

```
spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache();   -->   spark.read().textFile(logFile).cache();
```

**`read`**    should be **`read()`**